# How to prevent carriage return being copied to clipboard in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that is hashing the MAC address, then posting it into a file and a clipboard.

```
$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($MAC)))
$hash | clip
$hash | Out-File $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\this.txt
```

The issue I am having is that a carriage return is being exported to the clipboard. I don't want that.

Is there a way of stopping that happening?

Additional info - When I paste the text that is on the clipboard into a hex editor I see 0D0A

The clipboard function would be fine if I could just loose that some how?
Thanks

Comment: By the way, that's actually two characters: CR (carriage return) and LF (line feed). In other words, a Windows new line.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use PowerShell 5.0 or higher, [`Set-Clipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is available. It does not add any newline characters. So, your example would become:

```
$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($MAC)))
$hash | Set-Clipboard
$hash | Out-File $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\this.txt
```

Comment: If you're like me and keep forgetting: `Set-Alias clip Set-Clipboard`

Answer (score 0):

`$Hash.TrimEnd()` should clear any unicode whitespace at the end of the string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx

Comment: That does not actually work. My theory is that `clip` itself inserts the newline.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like `clip` itself appends the newline. So, let's do it the .NET way!

Here's a function that takes stdin and puts it in the clipboard:

```
function Out-ClipboardText
{
    param(  
        [Parameter(
            Position=0, 
            Mandatory=$true, 
            ValueFromPipeline=$true)
        ]
        [String]$text
    ) 

    process
    {
        powershell -sta -noprofile -command "add-type -an system.windows.forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText('$text')"
    }
}
```

<sup>Adapted from http://brianreiter.org/2010/09/03/copy-and-paste-with-clipboard-from-powershell/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/887406/1030702</sup>

Use it like so:

```
$hash | Out-ClipboardText
```

It uses the .NET clipboard function to set the text. Unfortunately, it's also a little slow and complicated because it needs to start a new PowerShell process in STA mode, as required for `Clipboard` ([source](http://brianreiter.org/2010/09/03/copy-and-paste-with-clipboard-from-powershell/)).